# Parameter name "id" in $.post doesn't work

Tags: post

I have the following code that I am using to post information to update an event. When I comment out the "id" param, the post succeeds and I receive information back from the server. However, when "id" is not commented out, nothing is sent.

```
var user = localStorage["user"];
var pw = localStorage["pw"];
var org = localStorage["org"];
var eventid = localStorage["eventid"];
$(function () {
        $("#submit").click(function () {
            if ($("#cancelled:checked")){
                cancel = "on";
            }else {
                cancel = "";
            }
            $.post(
                "/App/SetNewEvent/default.asp",
                {
                    user: user,
                    key: pw,
                    org: org,
                    id: eventid,
                    playdate: $("#playdate").val(),
                    start: $("#start").val(),
                    finish: $("#finish").val(),
                    location: $("#facilityid").val(),
                    tournament: $("#type").val(),
                    cancelled: cancel,
                    team: $("#teamid").val(),
                    homeopponent: $("#homeopponentid").val(),
                    schednote: $("#note").val()
                },
                function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            );
        });
    })
```

Comment: You sure eventid is defined and visible in the scope it is used in?

Comment: Have you tried seeing if it makes it to your server(debug the method) with the id?

Comment: Sent or received? What does your JavaScript console say?

Comment: @holodoc yes, these are globals. I have edited the code so you can see them.

Comment: @Blender the console is blank. When I comment out the ID param, it returns a response.

Comment: @MarkK: Then the error is with your server.

Comment: @Blender Thanks, I'll see what I can dig up.